# Maven Dependency Tree

Tags: maven

Estou tendo alguns problemas de conflitos de versão nas minhas dependencias do projetos e o comando `mvn dependency:tree` não está sendo o suficiente, pois tenho muitas dependencias e está dificil de identificar quais dependencias há a dependencia da biblioteca em conflito. Existe algum comando mais objetivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação do maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html), existe o comando:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=<biblioteca>
```

Eles irá retornar especificamente as dependências que dependem da biblioteca informada.

Um detalhe importante pra essa situação é o atributo `-Dverbose`, que instrui a árvore de dependência a exibir dependências conflitantes. Ou seja, você terá informações como `omitted for conflict with 2.0` que  ajudarão a encontrar os conflitos. Porém, esse atributo só é utilizável no Maven 2.0, pois na versão 3.0 do Maven o uso do -Dverbose pode resultar em alguns problemas segundo a [documentação](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html):

> **verbose** Whether to include omitted nodes in the serialized dependency
>   tree. Notice this feature actually uses Maven 2 algorithm and may give
>   wrong results when used with Maven 3.

É até por isso que ao executar o comando completo acima no Maven 2.0 poderá ser notado a mensagem:

> Using Maven 2 dependency tree to get verbose output, which may be inconsistent with actual Maven 3 resolution